# Adicionar 0 na frente do horário quando for menor que 10 para ajudar a diferenciar

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, layout

Acessei [esta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51180/14213) hoje e notei um pequeno detalhe que pode ser meio inútil, mas achei plausível de uma discussão construtiva.

Notem que todos os APs envolvidos tem postagens anteriores a 12h.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que ocorreu foi que de inicio eu fiquei meio em duvida sobre quem havia respondido primeiro, o Isvaldo ou o Bigown, pois `4:10` seria 4h da manhã ou 4h da tarde?
O logica foi obvia, o site é PT então 4h é manhã e 16h é tarde. Contudo ainda assim ele é proveniente do SO que é Inglês, então fiquei novamente em duvida se poderia estar faltando o AM, PM.
Olhando outras perguntas notei que haviam `15h`, `19h`, `23h`, então conclui que não, é assim mesmo.

#### Questão

- Não seria interessante manter sempre 4 dígitos? sendo `4:10` representado por `04:10`?

Comment: Pode ser mesmo.

Comment: Acho uma boa ideia, mas o horário com 4 dígitos é mais representativo do formato de 24h?

Comment: @Gabe, por isso abri para debate, para mim e algumas outras pessoas que conheço, se tem um `0` na frente então estaria diretamente relacionado à manhã, tarde `1`, noite `2`.

Comment: Eu acho que seria muito bom sim adicionar o `0` (zero) na frente.

Comment: @Gabe acho que o uso dos dois dígitos está em acordo com a ISO 8601.

Comment: A mim, sinceramente, não me faz diferença.

Comment: Eu sei que não resolve, mas quebra um galho. Há um recurso sutil. Coloque o mouse em cima da data e surgirá um título como um tooltip exibindo a data e hora no formato ISO 8601. Exemplo: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni3Vk.png. Se estiver num dispositivo touch sem mouse, aí complica...  Para mim também é confuso esses formatos sem "padrão oficial". Cada país adota um hábito visual amigável mas causa confusão. Imagine uma data como 10/6/12 (é 2012? 2010? junho? outubro?). Falei sobre data mas aplica-se para horário também.

Comment: Apoio a ideia. Fui um pouco ignorante algum tempo atrás quando reparei nisso e passei pela mesma situação, mas achei que fosse desnecessário abrir uma discussão e acabei me esquecendo.